# error: int cannot be dereferenced in java

Tags: java

I'm having an error called 'int cannot be dereferenced' on these lines of code. Errors point at all indices containing i, why?
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(e.getSource()==ui.lights[0][i]){
            ui.lights[0][i].setText("X");
            if(lights[1][i].getText()!=""){
                lights[1][i].setText("X");
            }
            if(i-1>=0){
                if(lights[0][i-1].getText()!="X")
                    lights[0][i-1].setText("X");
            }
            if(i+1<=4){
                if(lights[0][i+1].getText()!="X")
                    lights[0][i+1].setText("X");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you declared i somewhere in your code? If not, it should be  for(int i=0; etc..

Comment: also what is this object: `lights`

Comment: You'll need to show us the declaration of `e`, `ui`, `ui.lights`, and `lights`.  My guess is that `lights` is an `int[][]`.

Comment: Right the point @Kevin whitout know what `lights` would be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ui.lights[0][i].setText("X");
```

`int` is a primitive type. it is not an object. it does not have methods.

when you're calling `.setText()`, you're assuming that `ui.lights[0][i]` is an object that has that method. but from your description, it seems that it's just an `int`.

Either that, or `ui` itself is just an `int`.

Comment: What if the `lights` is just an array of an object that has this method ?

Comment: lol. haha. how careless am i. thanks! i'll check ur answer within 10 min.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, i just forgot to put the object ui. :)